# pass field value to subreport or list

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working with jasperreport 6.5.1, I wanna display in each page the employee details and the list of the visited addresses.
I have 2 tables `employee {id, name, firstName...}`and`visited_addresses{id, name, id_emp...}`

I tried firstly to use a jasper sub_report element but I didn't found how to pass the id of the employee who I wanna get his visited addresses

then I tried to use the list element, but I'm struggled with the same problem.
How can I pass the id field to my sub_report or my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to select the employee id with the query in your main report and then add it as parameter to the subreport.

The solution explained [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/981401/how-do-i-pass-field-subreport-parameter) - the version of iReport should not make a difference.

Basically it says:

> Click on sub report. in the properties section got to parameters. and add the parameters which you want communicate through main report to subreport.